# Limit duplicated values in joined query to show only for first instance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am joining two tables in a way that the query returns:

| parent.name | child.name | child.col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | foo |
| Second | A | foo |
| Third | A | foo |
| Fourth | B | bar |
| Fifth | C | baz |
| Sixth | C | baz |

I only need the data in the `child.col` field to show for the first time it appears.
I've tried looking into using windows or grouping by `child.name` and unioning all but the first row, but the simplest solution I've thought of is to count the index of each unique child like so:

| parent.name | child.name | child.col | instance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | foo | 1 |
| Second | A | foo | 2 |
| Third | A | foo | 3 |
| Fourth | B | bar | 1 |
| Fifth | C | baz | 1 |
| Sixth | C | baz | 2 |

Then I can use a case statement to only show the `child.col` value if `instance == 1`.

I can't figure out how to achieve this though. The real queries I'm working with are monsters, so the only code I have to show is the simple one I wrote to create the above example:

```sql
SELECT parent.name, child.name, child.col
FROM parent, child
WHERE parent.match = child.match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Second, you can use `row_number()` with `case`:

```
SELECT p.name,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY p.name) = 1
             THEN c.name
        END) as name,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY p.name) = 1
             THEN c.col
        END) as col
FROM parent p JOIN
     child c
     ON p.match = c.match
ORDER BY c.name, p.name;
```

Note that the outer aggregation is needed to be sure that the "first" row in each group has the values.

Comment: 1) That was a quick example, the real query uses big boy joins but thank you for letting me know. 
2) Thank you, that was a lot easier than I expected ️